# Formatar moeda em um UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Preciso criar um UITextField para adicionar valores de dinheiro. Mas preciso que o usuário veja o valor sendo adicionado no UITextField na ordem que o usuário digitar. Exemplo:
Usuário digita 1 - no UITextField aparece 0,01
Usuário digita 5 - no UITextField aparece 0,15
Usuário digita 0 - no UITextField aparece 1,50

Ai entra meu problema, quando o usuário digita o 4º digito, no meu caso esta aparecendo 1,5,00 e não 15,00 como desejo.

Segue o código da formatação:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *valueTextFieldFormatter= [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [valueTextFieldFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#0,0"];
    [valueTextFieldFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSString *num = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

    textField.text = [valueTextFieldFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[num floatValue]]];
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O código que eu informei esta dentro do método `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um pouco diferente. Dessa forma tenho o número informado pelo usuário formatado no `UITextField`(valueTextField.text) e tenho uma versão dele com apenas números(storeValue) para o caso de precisar fazer contas e essas coisas.

Na `@interface`:

```objc
   NSMutableString *storeValue;
   NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter;
```

Na `viewDidLoad:`:

```objc
    storeValue = [NSMutableString new];
    numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

E na `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`

```objc
    if (textField == valueTextField) {
        if (string.length == 0) {
            int length = (storeValue.length - 1);
            if (length >= 0) {
                NSRange range = NSMakeRange(length, 1);
                [storeValue deleteCharactersInRange:range];
            };
        } else if ([textField.text length] <= 7) {
            [storeValue appendString:string];
        }

        NSString *newText = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:([storeValue doubleValue] / 100)] ];
        [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newText]];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
```

Answer (score 6):

David, há formas mais simples de resolver este problema. Tente trocando o style do number para NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle e colocando um local como referência para a formatação.

```
NSNumberFormatter *n = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[n setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"];
[n setLocale:locale];
NSString *saída = [n stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:125.98]];
```

A saída será R$125,98.

Comment: Cara, no seu exemplo temos o número completo já. No meu caso o número vai se formando conforme o usuário vai digitando. Não tive tempo para mexer hoje, mas o pouco que teste ficou tipo:1 R$0,001... 2 R$1,002.. 3 R$1.005,003

Comment: Rafael, se eu não fizer o `setLocale`, ele pega a `locale` da região onde o aparelho está? Ou usa o default americano?

Comment: Se o `locale` não for configurado então será utilizado o que estiver definido nas configurações do aparelho.

Answer (score 3):

Eu tenho algo um pouco diferente no `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` em um aplicativo meu funcionando da forma que você quer.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField tag] == 1) { // Só para identificar o campo de moeda
        NSString *replaced = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSDecimalNumber *amount = (NSDecimalNumber*) [self.formatter numberFromString:replaced];
        if (amount == nil) {
            return NO;
        }
        short powerOf10 = 0;
        if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
            powerOf10 = -self.formatter.maximumFractionDigits;
        } else if (range.location + self.formatter.maximumFractionDigits >= textField.text.length) {
            if (range.length) {
                powerOf10 = -range.length;
            } else {
                powerOf10 = [string length];
            }
        }
        amount = [amount decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:powerOf10];
        textField.text = [self.formatter stringFromNumber:amount];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

E no `viewDidLoad:` tenho a minha propriedade `formatter` utilizado acima:

```
self.formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[self.formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[self.formatter setLenient:YES];
[self.formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:YES];
[self.formatter setCurrencySymbol:@""];
[self.formatter setInternationalCurrencySymbol:@""];
```

Não é necessário o **locale**, já que ele já está definido nas configurações do aparelho, a menos que você queira algum diferente.

Comment: Duvidas, para que serve os comandos: `setLenient`, `setCurrencySymbol` e `setInternationalCurrencySymbol`? Tentei usar no meu e não vi mudança...

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do David Batista foi muito útil.

Estou escrevendo o código em Swift e funcionou muito bem.

```
if ((string as NSString).length == 0) {
        var length = (storeValue.length - 1);
        if (length >= 0) {
            var range = NSMakeRange(length, 1)

            storeValue.deleteCharactersInRange(range)
        }
    } else if ( (textField.text as NSString).length <= 15) {
        storeValue.appendString(string)
    }

    var newText = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(NSNumber(double: storeValue.doubleValue/100))
    textField.text = NSString(format: "%@", newText!) as String

    return false
```