# Formatar moeda Brasil em Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, internacionalização

Tenho uma string já formatada, gostaria transforma-la em float e depois em um número formatado para moeda.

entrada      saída
1.234,10     1234.1 ou 1234.1

entrada      saída
1.234.10     1.234,10

Comment: Se está usando `float` para representar dinheiro você já está com um problema bem mais sério que formatação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38138/101 e acho que a formatação já foi respondida aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8190/101

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo assim:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSLocale *localizableIdentifier = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"pt_BR"];
[formatter setLocale:localizableIdentifier];
float money = 300.23f;
NSNumber *meuDinheiro = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:money];

NSString *newString = [formatter stringFromNumber:meuDinheiro];
NSLog(@"Você me deve: %@", newString);
```